# Combination filters Isotope Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, filter, jquery-isotope

I use Isotope on my Wordpress Website to filter my custom post. I have a CPT Film (`production`) and multiple taxonomies : `type` (Animation / Horror...), `years` (2012 / 2013) and so on.

For the moment I can sort by years and every things work fine with this code in my template page:

```
<div class="row">
    <ul id="filters">
        <li>Selectionner</li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">Toutes les années</a></li>
        <?php 
            $terms = get_terms("annee"); // get all categories, but you can use any taxonomy
            $count = count($terms); //How many are they?
            if ( $count > 0 ){  //If there are more than 0 terms
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  //for each term:
                    echo "<li><a href='#' data-filter='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "</a></li>\n";
                    //create a list item with the current term slug for sorting, and name for label
                }
            } 
        ?>
</ul>
```

After the list, the loop that show all post and sort by years:

```
<?php 
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
     'posts_per_page' => 16,
     'post_type' => array( 'production' )
)); //Check the WP_Query docs to see how you can limit which posts to display ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div id="isotope-list">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
            $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "annee" );  //Get the terms for this particular item
            $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms
                foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
                    $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
                }
            ?> 
            <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item three columns gallery grid"> <?php // 'item' is used as an identifier (see Setp 5, line 6) ?>

                   <figure class="effect-ming">
                         <?php the_post_thumbnail('miniature-film');  ?>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2><?php the_title('') ?></h2>
                            <p class="serif"><?php the_field('realisation'); ?><p>
                        </figcaption>       

                    </figure>
            </div> <!-- end item -->
        <?php endwhile;  ?>
<?php else : ?>
<p>Aucun résultat ne correspond à votre recherche </p>
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/catalogue">Retour au catalogue</a>
</div> <!-- end isotope-list -->
<?php endif; ?>                 
</div>
```

And the following javascript:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var $container = $('#isotope-list'); //The ID for the list with all the blog posts
    $container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
        itemSelector : '.item', 
        layoutMode : 'masonry'
    });

    //Add the class selected to the item that is clicked, and remove from the others
    var $optionSets = $('#filters '),
    $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

    $optionLinks.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // don't proceed if already selected
        if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
            return false;
        }
        var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
        $optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');

        //When an item is clicked, sort the items.
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

        return false;
    });

});

(function( $ ) {
    $( function() {

        var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
            itemSelector: '.element-item',
            layoutMode: 'fitRows'
        });

        $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
            var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
            $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

But **I want to make multiple filters like years** and use them at the same time, but I don't know how to do that.

I have tried to duplicate the code I used  for `years` and change the slug by `"type"` but it didn't worked.

Here is an example that show you what I want to do: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/GFbAs

It iss made with isotope, not with Wordpress functions, so I don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 1):

First, add a new custom data parameter to your links, such as `data-filter-two=""`

Then add an additional jQuery click function to handle that filtering -

```
$('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter-two');
    $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response it's seems to be close to solution but i have a new problem .. in the loop i have to get the terms in the loop , it works with one like this       $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "genre");  but i can't put another one

Comment: Can you update your question with the relevant issue? Or if it's unrelated to the initial problem, perhaps post a new question.